# Как загрузить изображение в timge через проводник?

Tags: delphi, изображения

```
image1.Picture.LoadFromFile();
```

Подскажите, где почитать о работе с изображениями в дельфи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В любом поисковике наберите свой вопрос)

Тут например можете почитать:

http://mydelphiprogramms.jimdo.com/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-delphi/

http://www.snkey.net/books/delphi/ch3-5.html